# Why is the base prefix in a relative IRI for an id shortened before expansion?

Tags: json-ld, base-url

I have a JSON-LD document in which the base prefix is not expanded as I expect but shortened first to its root and then the `@id` data is appended:

```json
{
    "@context": {
        "tag": "@type",
        "@base": "http://example.com/base#auth-1/",
        "Line": "lit:Line",
        "load": "book:load",
        "book": "http://gerastree.at/auth-1/",
        "lnum": "lit:lnum",
        "lline": {
            "@language": "deu",
            "@id": "lit:lines"
        },
        "lit": "http://gerastree.at/lit_2014#",
        "lid": "@id"
    },
    "loadid": "loadIDstring",
    "load": [
        {
            "tag": "Line",
            "lnum": 1,
            "lline": "asdf1",
            "lid": "1"
        },
        {
            "tag": "Line",
            "lnum": 2,
            "lline": "asdf2",
            "lid": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

RIOT (or the playground) gives then:

```
 riot --syntax=jsonld --output=turtle lines.jsonld
@prefix lit:  <http://gerastree.at/lit_2014#> .
@prefix book:  <http://gerastree.at/auth-1/> .

_:b0    book:load  <http://example.com/1> ;
        book:load  <http://example.com/2> .

<http://example.com/1>
        <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  lit:Line ;
        lit:lines  "asdf1"@deu ;
        lit:lnum   1 .

<http://example.com/2>
        <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>  lit:Line ;
        lit:lines  "asdf2"@deu ;
        lit:lnum   2 .
```

I cannot understand why the ids of the two lines are just `<http://example.com/2>` and not `<http://example.com/base#auth-1/2>`. Why is the base prefix shortened? What can I change to avoid this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`@base`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-json-ld-20140116/#base-iri) follows RFC 3986’s [Establishing a Base URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.1), which says (bold emphasis mine):

> If the base URI is obtained from a URI reference, then that reference must be converted to absolute form and **stripped of any fragment component** prior to its use as a base URI.

So your

```json
"@base": "http://example.com/base#auth-1/",
```

will result in this base IRI:

```json
http://example.com/base
```

---

If you specify `"lid": "#auth-1/2"` instead of `"lid": "2"`, you end up with `http://example.com/base#auth-1/2`.

Alternatively, you could define a prefix for these values, like

```json
"foobar": "http://example.com/base#auth-1/"
```

and use

```json
"lid": "foobar:2"
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation which I could not have found (perhaps the json-ld docs could include a warning?). The goal was, to build IRIs for tree structured data by giving each level its context and pass an addition to the base for each. I guess I can achieve the same with changing a prefix.

Comment: I would suggest to change the Example 16 in the JSON-LD 1.0 document. It shows an `"@base" : "http://example.com/document.jsonld"` and does not indicate, that the `document.jsonid` part is dropped without warning. It seems misleading (at least it was pointing me in believing that base would be used literally).

Comment: @user855443: The surrounding text explains why it can be useful to specify a base IRI like that: if you provide `"@id": ""` (an empty value), it resolves to this base IRI including the path `/document.jsonld`.